# how watchpoint on register works

Tags: gdb, debuggers, lldb

`GDB` has an option to set watchpoint on register*, how does it work ? what happens during context switching ? why the only implementation is for [mips](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/third_party/gdb/+/refs/heads/master/gdb/mips-linux-nat.c) ?

Is there a way to make it work for `lldb` also ?

- *`watch $eax == 0x0000ffff`

Answer (score 2):

You can probably find the details in GDB’s source code but I *think* it just single-steps the program until the condition matches. IIRC this is done for any condition that can’t be handled by a hardware breakpoint.

Comment: there is a link to GDB source code in the question, can you explain how it's not effected by context switch ?

Comment: @Iddo: The hardware registers are not sensitive to context switching. Usually, they are just ignored by the OS.

Comment: can you please provide a prove for that statement ? and why only implementation are for MIPS ?